# Definition of a simple characteristic for an elliptic operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-operators

Could one give a definition of a simple characteristic for an elliptic operator?

For example, I have an elliptic operator:
\begin{equation}
 P(x,D) = \sum\limits_{|\alpha|=2m}a_{\alpha}(x)D^{\alpha} + 
 R(x,D), \, x\in \Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2,
\end{equation}
where $R(x,D)$ is an operator of degree less than $2m$.

How can I check that it's characteristics are simple? In particular, I don't understand the phrase: "complex characteristics are simple".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treves -- Linear Partial Differential equations